# NoSQL insert collection data to another one

Tags: database, nosql

I have 2 collection like:

Users data:

```
{
  id:"uid_1",
  name:"user1",
  skills:[]
}
```

Skills data like:

```
{  
 id:"skill_1",
 name:"skill1" 
}
```

My question is:

Should I insert whole `skill` document insert to an `user's` or just `skill id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go either way. It depends on how you want to design, and the retrieval technique will differ.
*Assuming a user can have multiple skills:*

**First approach**: Insert whole **skill** document to a **user**'s: **user** collection will see it as a list of **skill** objects, and you can retrieve it directly using array retrieval technique.

**Second approach**: Insert only the **skills.id**: **user**'s collection will see it as a list of string. You might have to use to separate queries for the two collections or use an **aggregation pipeline** to join the two collections when required.